# <ul> within <ol><li> still showing numbers

Tags: html, list, nested

My personal website using a school template is behaving very weirdly. I tried to nest a ul within an ol. The parent ol numbers still show up in front of the ul item dots. For example, I typed

```html
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b
    <ul>
      <li>b1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

to expect

1. a
2. b

   - b1

What I get instead looks like this:

[image]

It is as if nesting is not allowed. Once I disable styles the list displays properly. What command in CSS could have caused this?

Comment: don't know why the picture didn't show up. How the above code appears is like

1. a
2. b
    1. * b1.

The number 1 appears before the *b1. Sorry I hope the meaning is through.

Comment: I put your code in a stacksnippet and it doesn't display what you claim it does

Comment: What styles are you using on this list, since you say it works when you "disable styles"?

Comment: I know the problem is in my css file. It's from my school. I have it locally. How can I post it? I didn't specifically use a particular style. By "disable styles" I meant checking that menu option in Safari on Mac under the Develop menu.

Comment: Ok here are the CSS definitions regarding list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXTyx.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoukD.png sorry I don't have enough reps to post them directly in the question